# Read a limited no of Elements from XML

Tags: java, xml, streaming

I have a large XML file (many MBs) that I cannot afford to download as a whole.

```
<doc>
   <element>...</element>
   <element>...</element>
   ...
   <element>...</element>
</doc>
```

I need to read this XML from the web (or better - stream it) and then take the first N `element`s from its body to have them processed with an XSLT template.

What library/technique do you recommend for such a task? I am writing in Java.

Kindest regards,
Q.

Comment: use SAX instead of DOM to parse the XML elements while you're reading them. When you have read enough, stop reading from the InputStream things and feed it to your XSLT processor.

Comment: @Alex I agree with you to use SAX, but the XSLT processor will not accept a fragment of an xml file, it needs a valid file/tree/structure. Unless of course you manually add the closing doc tag, before feeding it to the XSLT processor

Comment: @Kennet I don't think there is a way to add closing doc tag if it was never read from the stream. So in any case, you have to add it manually.

Comment: When you override the startElement keep a reference to each opening tag in order. This way when you have read enough data you already what tags you need to close and in what order. Even if it does not contains all the data, the XML element is correct and thus can be fed to the XSLT processor. But the answer of @Max below is OK, STAX is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use STAX to read the elements and redirect a subset of them to a different stream:

```
final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
final XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
final XMLEventReader xmlReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(yourInputStream);
final XMLEventWriter xmlWriter = xmlOutputFactory .createXMLEventWriter(yourOutputStream); //The place where the resulting partial XML will go

while (xmlReader.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent event = xmlReader.nextEvent();

    if (event ... some validation) {
        xmlWriter.add(event); //Forward it to xmlWriter
    }

    if (we have read enough elements) {
        break;
    }
}
xmlReader.close();
xmlWriter.flush();
xmlWriter.close();
```

**Addition:**

To write the closing tag, you should create a close tag event and pass it to same `XMLEventWriter` object whenever you need. For that you need an instance of `XMLEventFactory`. Here's example of writing a closing tag:

```
XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
XMLEvent closeTagEvent = eventFactory.createEndElement("prefix", "http://namespace.com", "elementName");
//This will create a closing tag event for a previously opened <prefix:elementName xmlns:prefix="http://namespace.com">

xmlWriter.add(closeTagEvent);

xmlWriter.flush();
xmlWriter.close();
```

P.S. Sorry for confusion with one of my comments suggesting to use `XMLStreamWriter`. I had never used `XMLEventWriter` so did not know how to use it properly until now.

Comment: The **partial xml** comment means that your snippet will download only a part of the online XML and close all necessary xml tags, am I right? Then I just read the partial XML and do whatever I please?

Comment: No, you will still have to write the closing tags to `yourOutputStream` some way manually. STAX does not ensure all tags are closed, it just simplifies reading/writing XML from/to streams without bothering about XML syntax. You have 2 options: 1. Write closing tags directly into `yourOutputStream` as text. 2. Wrap yourOutputStream with XMLStreamWriter and write closing tags though it.

Comment: Yes, each time `xmlReader.nextEvent()` is called, it starts reading data from `inputStream` until whole `event` is read. For example, the moment it gets `<someOpeningTag>` - it will stop reading from the stream, as this data is enough for triggering a begin_element event. So basically, it's what you need.

Comment: When trying to write the last closing tag, I get `No element was found to write: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` - any idea why?

Comment: @Queequeg See addition to my answer and disregard my comment about XMLStreamWriter.